# conflicting declaration error when compiling in Rcpp, but g++ works fine

Tags: r, rcpp, hdfql

I am trying to compile an Rcpp package that relies on the external library [HDFql](http://hdfql.com).

First, I tried compiling a plain .cpp file following the directions in the [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf), **which worked fine**:

```
g++ example.cpp -I./include/HDFql ./HDFql/libHDFql.a -fopenmp -ldl
```

where the `./include/HDFql` folder contains the header files and `./HDFql/libHDFql.a` is the static library.

Then I tried doing the equivalent in an Rcpp package. My package directory structure is

```
|- R
  |- script. r
|- src
  |- HDFql
    |- libHDFql.a
  |- example.cpp
  |- Makevars
|-inst
  |- include
    |- HDFql
      |- ... header files...
```

Where the contents of `Makevars` is

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include/HDFql/
PKG_LIBS = ./HDFql/libHDFql.a
LDLIBS = -fopenmp -ldl
```

I also added `#include <Rcpp.h>` to `example.cpp`. Running `devtools::document()` yields

> ../inst/include/HDFql/H5public.h:156:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long long int ssize_t’
>    typedef long long ssize_t;

Which I don't understand at all. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

**EDIT** [link to Github repository](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/RcppHDFql)

Comment: is your project on github?

Comment: Looks like Rcpp's `typedef` for `long long` and the one for your library source disagree. So make the definition in your library conditional via `#ifndef ....` ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU see my edit (link at bottom).

Comment: @Dirk, not sure what you mean? HDFql is an external library someone else has developed... or is this something I would put in `example.cpp`?

Comment: @mikeck: https://github.com/mkoohafkan/RcppHDFql/blob/f112427521bcf36f914429f2b743f4828204a09b/inst/include/HDFql/H5public.h#L156  You can define something in your `example.cpp` before the `#include` to avoid this redefinition.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry @Dirk, I still don't understand. The headers in include/HDFql are part of the HDFql distribution along with libHDFql.a. I thought include guards are used to prevent the same header being included twice? But in this case I have two header files using the same name for different purposes so I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: According to HDFql release notes (http://www.hdfql.com/resources/RELEASE.txt), the issue (of conflicting with other C/C++ header dependencies) has been solved in version 2.0.0