# Namespace exists but still getting declaration conflicts?

Tags: c++, namespaces, hdfql

I am working with the [HDFql](http://hdfql.com) C++ wrapper library and trying to integrate it with R via Rcpp. I'm an experienced coder in general, but not in C++ specifically. I made [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806979/conflicting-declaration-error-when-compiling-in-rcpp-but-g-works-fine) about trying to resolve an issue with declaration conflicts. The compiler error message is copied below:

```
../inst/include/HDFql/H5public.h:156:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef long long int ssize_t’ typedef long long ssize_t;
```

([Link to the actual declaration in the header file](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/RcppHDFql/blob/f112427521bcf36f914429f2b743f4828204a09b/inst/include/HDFql/H5public.h#L156))

Basically, both HDFql and Rcpp have `typedef`s for `long long` and they conflict. However, the HDFql wrapper defines it's own namespace [on this line right here](https://github.com/mkoohafkan/RcppHDFql/blob/master/inst/include/HDFql/HDFql.hpp#L77), so I don't understand why I'm getting this conflict in the first place (I thought that's what namespaces are for!). I'm hoping a C++ guru can help me with two questions:

1. **Why is this conflict happening even though the library is using a namespace?** (*EDIT: @Igor answered this in comment*)
2. Pretend I'm the developer of the HDFql C++ wrapper (I'm not). **How would I change the wrapper library or namespace structure so that these types of conflict can't occur?** (*Edit: maybe write a second wrapper for HDFql as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678312/2375551)?*)

I'd appreciate any insights you have!

Comment: I am pretty sure forum/issue tracker of the named library would be much more appropriate than general C++ discussion on SO.

Comment: Is `ssize_t` defined inside the namespace?  Are you using `using namespace namespace_name;`?

Comment: Yes, `HDFql.hpp` defines a namespace. But `ssize_t` declaration is in a different header, `H5public.h`, and in the global namespace. Further, it's in `extern "C"` section, which suggests it's intended to be usable from C, and so can't possibly be in a namespace.

Comment: And `ssize_t` is also something which can be declared by dozen of system headers.

Comment: @SergeyA, I agree that for resolving this issue specifically I should seek out the library forum/issue tracker, but I am trying to understand the problem *in general*.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, I think I understand the answer to Question 1 now. If you have any thoughts or general guidance on Question 2, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm not `using` but I think @Igor's comment explains it. `ssize_t` is defined outside of the namespace.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you, but I need you to dumb it down for me ;) I would appreciate it if you could explain why and how defining my own version of `H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T` would solve the issue (wouldn't I then have 3 definitions?) and would accept+upvote such an answer.

Comment: The whole section where `ssize_t` is defined is surrounded by `#if H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T==0  ... #endif`. So if `H5_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T` is defined, externally, to something other than zero, the whole section will be skipped. However, upon closer inspection, you can't just set it to any odd non-zero value - it's apparently expected to be defined to the value equal to `sizeof(ssize_t)`. I imagine some other parts of the code might rely on that.

Comment: According to HDFql release notes (http://www.hdfql.com/resources/RELEASE.txt), the issue (of conflicting with other C/C++ header dependencies) has been solved in version 2.0.0